# Why does "Show" Segue Update UITableViewCells but not reloadData()?

Tags: swift

I have a problem which iv been dealing with for a long time just never got around to seeing why.

Problem

I have a UItableview and load data into it from Firebase. When I segue "show" from ViewController #1 to ViewController #2 (with the UITableView) the firebase data is loaded into the cells.

Each cell has a UITableViewRowAction "delete" which basically deletes the Firebase information. But when i press the button..it does delete the Firebase information but not the cell. In order for that UITableView to update I have to segue "show" back to any other ViewController and come back to ViewController #2 for it to update.

** This method only updates if there is more than 1 UITableViewCell in the table

Problem #2 - Only 1 UITableViewCell

Now if there is only 1 UITableViewCell loaded and I "delete" it....it never goes away unless I create a new UITableViewCell in ViewController #2.

What have i tried?

```
self.tableView.endUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Iv literally plugged reloadData() anywhere I could to see if would reload data but it just wont reload it!

```
let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
            self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView?(
                self.tableView,
                commitEditingStyle: .Delete,
                forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath
            )
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            let uid = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as! String // uid
            DataService.dataService.deleteAudio(uid, project: self.sharedRec.projectName, vocalString: self.sharedRec.audioString )

            let currURL = self.sharedRec.audioString
            let url = "\(currURL).caf"

            //Document Directory
            let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
            // Full File to Delete Location
            let fileURL = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(url)
            // This is to print out all directory files
            let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!

            do {
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                print("DELETED LOCAL RECORD")

                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(fileURL)
                print("file deleted \(fileURL)")
                let directoryContents = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions())
                print("PRINT LOCAL DIC\(directoryContents)") // NOT WORKING
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic) // SHOWS ERROR
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
            return
        })
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

1. In function `commitEditingStyle` delete data from your array, database etc.
2. Decrement your current row count.
3. tableView.beginUpdates()
4. tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
5. tableView.endUpdates()

Comment: Are you saying to add beginUpdates  before the data is deleted and endUpdates after? Also the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths is giving an error.. iv updated the code above! thank you so much for helping !

Comment: Refer this example. This is how you should do the delete row operation. [link](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/delete-rows-table-view-ios8-swift)